# Trouble centering simple jquery sideshow with nav under

Tags: jquery

Im currently recoding my site. Keeping it very minimal. But I am having trouble getting the links nav to behave properly. I want them to sit underneath the images about 50px's. Currently on the nav div I have a margin-top value of around 550px. But once you get it on a different size screen it obviously will be higher or lower depending on screen size. I'm obviously very new and would appreciate the help greatly!

You can view my site here:
[www.twentyfivethree.com](http://www.twentyfivethree.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to achieve consistent positioning vertically and horizontally, regardless of screen size, is repeat the same css you have for the images. Something like this:

```
.nav {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:380px;
  height:20px;
  margin-left:-190px;
  margin-top:180px;
}
```

This is pretty much the same process applied to the navigation. You will need adjust the  pixel dimensions to fit your layout and design.